# Onboarding welcome or a tutorial?

Tags: tutorial

we are preparing a tutorial for a new mobile and web app, but I have read that it's better to start with an onboarding welcome four slide to highlight the added value of our application. So.....what is the best option? Could I start with an onboarding and later to have an option for video tutorials?

Thanks and regards,
Alejandro.

Answer (score 3):

Onboarding is not the same as highlighting different features.
Onboarding should involve the user, in best case the user finishes a task that represents what he will mainly be doing while using the app to get him started.

If your app is complex then onboarding is recommended, but keep it mind that the user should have the possibility to skip the onbarding at any time because many users just don't like to get forced to finish onboarding.

Regarding the video tutorials, if your onboarding is decent i don't think video tutorials are needed, at least i have never used an application where onboarding was good and i needed additional video tutorials just to use it. Keep in mind that people using mobile apps don't really want to be bothered by watching video tutorials just to be able to use the app, you have a lot of competition and the slightest annoyance will make users uninstall your app.

Comment: Some good points there. For some pointers about what's good and bad in on boarding it's worth checking out  https://www.useronboard.com/

Comment: To add some comments on the video tutorials. They open a whole new bag of trouble. You have to make sure your users will be engaged for the whole length of the video. You need to make sure people with hearing disabilities (or not any headphones) are still able to understand what's happening. And if you add subtitles you need to ensure they are legible on any small mobile screen. 

There's very few cases (if any) where video tutorials are good for onboarding.